# perl Gtk2::WebKit: how to do a full page screenshot

Tags: perl, webkit

I'm using the perl module [`Gtk2::WebKit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Gtk2%3a%3aWebKit) to create a browser and take a screenshot of a web page.  There is no problem to take a screenshot of the visible portion of the page (the window size).  However, how can I take a screenshot of the full page, even the part not visible in the window?

Answer (score 3):

I think [**this**](https://github.com/potyl/Webkit/blob/master/screenshot.pl) is what you're looking for. I found it on Github.

**screenshot.pl - Take a screenshot**

Save a page as an SVG:

```
screenshot.pl --type svg http://www.google.com/
```

Save a page as a PDF:

```
screenshot.pl --output cpan.pdf http://search.cpan.org/
```

Save an element of a page taken from an XPath query as a PNG:

```
screenshot.pl --output ba.png --xpath 'id("content")' http://bratislava.pm.org/
```

Comment: it uses GTK3, not GTk2. I can't install Gtk3 on CentOS 6.5

Comment: Why not on 6.5? Check this: http://linuxfonts.narod.ru/compiling-and-installing-gtk3-in-centos6.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is my **GTK2** solution to this problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Gtk2 -init;
use Gtk2::WebKit;
use Data::Dumper; 

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
my $sw     = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new;
my $view   = Gtk2::WebKit::WebView->new;
my $factor = 0;

$window->set_default_size(Gtk2::Gdk->screen_width, Gtk2::Gdk->screen_height);
$window->set_border_width(1);
$sw->add($view);
$window->add($sw);

$window ->signal_connect( 'destroy' => \&delete_event );
$view->signal_connect( 'load-finished' => \&prepare_zoom);

$view->set_full_content_zoom(TRUE);
$view->signal_connect( 'size-allocate' => \&screenshot);
$view->open('http://stackoverflow.com/questions');

$window->show_all;
Gtk2->main;


#####################################
sub delete_event {
    Gtk2->main_quit;
    return FALSE;
}  
#####################################

sub prepare_zoom {
    $adj = $sw->get_vadjustment();
    $factor = $adj->page_size/$adj->upper;
    $view->set_zoom_level($factor);
}

sub screenshot {
    return unless defined($window->window) && $factor>0;
    my ($width, $height) = $window->window->get_size;
    my $sWidth=$width*$factor;

    my $gdkpixbuf = Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new ('rgb', 0, 8, $width, $height);
    $gdkpixbuf->get_from_drawable($window->window, 
            undef, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

    $gdkpixbuf->save ("screenshot.jpg", 'jpeg', quality => 100);
        #Gtk2->main_quit;
    return FALSE;
}
```

This code works, but I'm not a **GTK2 / Webkit** expert, so I'm sure it can be written in a better way.

The idea behind it is simple:

1. Load the page
2. Get full page size and visible page size, then calculate the scale factor needed to see the full page content
3. Scale the page using that scale factor
4. Grab the screenshot

**NOTES**

- Depends where you want to apply it, the scale factor calculation may need some corrections
- You can crop the screenshot (to remove the blank areas) adjusting the values passed to [get_from_drawable](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Gdk/Pixbuf.html#pixbuf_Gtk2_Gdk_Pixb7).

Comment: Clever trick, but I can't use it since I need the picture in the original size.

Comment: You could use xvfb (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to do that. Basically calculate the dimensions of the target web, invoke xvfb with such dimensions and load the webpage in it.